# Displaying Comments Under a Post

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm new to this and having trouble displaying the comments of a post in a table view with two cells (one cell = post, second cell = comments). Here is my code for the View Controller:

```
import UIKit

class PostDetailViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    var postId = ""
    var post = Post()
    var user = User()
    var comments = [Comment]()
    var users = [User]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.dataSource = self
        print("postId = \(postId)")
        loadPost()
        loadComments()
    }

    func loadPost() {
        API.Post.observePost(withId: postId) { (post) in
            guard let postUid = post.uid else {
                return
            }
            self.fetchUser(uid: postUid, completed: {
                self.post = post
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            })
            self.navigationItem.title = post.title
        }
    }

    func fetchUser(uid: String, completed: @escaping () -> Void ) {
        API.User.observeUser(withId: uid, completion: {
            user in
            self.user = user
            completed()
        })
    }

    func loadComments() {API.Post_Comment.REF_POST_COMMENTS.child(self.postId).observe(.childAdded, with: {
            snapshot in
            API.Comment.observeComments(withPostId: snapshot.key, completion: { comment in
                self.fetchUser(uid: comment.uid!, completed: {
                    self.comments.append(comment)
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                })

            })
        })
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "Detail_CommentSegue" {
            let commentVC = segue.destination as! CommentViewController
            let postId = sender as! String
            commentVC.postId = postId
        }

        if segue.identifier == "Detail_ProfileUserSegue" {
            let profileVC = segue.destination as! ProfileUserViewController
            let userId = sender as! String
            profileVC.userId = userId
        }

    }

    }

    extension PostDetailViewController: UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return comments.count + 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        if indexPath.row == 0 {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "DetailPostCell", for: indexPath) as! DetailTableViewCell
            cell.post = post
            cell.user = user
            cell.delegate = self
            return cell
        } else {
            let commentCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Detail_CommentCell") as! CommentTableViewCell
            let comment = comments[indexPath.row]
            let user = users[indexPath.row]
            commentCell.comment = comment
            commentCell.user = user
            return commentCell
        }
    }
    }

    extension PostDetailViewController: DetailTableViewCellDelegate {
    func goToCommentVC(postId: String) {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "Detail_CommentSegue", sender: postId)
    }
    func goToProfileUserVC(userId: String) {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "Detail_ProfileUserSegue", sender: userId)
    }
}
```

The error I'm getting is at:

```
let comment = comments[indexPath.row]
```

> "fatal error: Index out of range"

There are comments and they appear on the Comments View Controller without issue. I realize the error has something to do with calling two cells but I am unable to figure out a fix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not accounting for the first row when getting a value from your arrays.

The simple fix is to update `cellForRowAt` as follows:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if indexPath.row == 0 {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "DetailPostCell", for: indexPath) as! DetailTableViewCell
        cell.post = post
        cell.user = user
        cell.delegate = self
        return cell
    } else {
        let commentCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Detail_CommentCell") as! CommentTableViewCell
        let comment = comments[indexPath.row - 1] // here
        let user = users[indexPath.row - 1] // here
        commentCell.comment = comment
        commentCell.user = user
        return commentCell
    }
}
```

Note the two minor changes marked `// here`. The idea is that `comment[0]` is at row 1.

Some better suggestions:

1. Do not have multiple arrays. Have one array for your data. Define a structure that holds all of the data for one row. Then have one array of those structures. This makes your data easier to handle and makes things like sorting and filtering vastly simpler.
2. Consider putting your different data in different sections instead of all in one section.

Comment: Thanks! That worked for comment, but not for user - I think because user is getting called above in the first cell? Is that correct?

Comment: Actually I figured that out. I wasn't fetching the user for the comment properly. Have added that and it works now too. Thanks for your help!